# SSL certificate pinning in iOS app using objective C for React Native Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, react-native, mobile, ssl-certificate

I want to embed clients SSL certificate for iOS app using objective C for my React native project.
I have tried lots of solutions but not getting any luck with it.

So we have clients SSL certificate (.pem) which we need embed so that our API will work. I am getting 403 when calling our API I am sharing my code.

```
**MyURLSessionDelegate.mm**

#import "MyURLSessionDelegate.h"
#import <Security/Security.h>

@implementation MyURLSessionDelegate

+ (instancetype)sharedInstance {
    static MyURLSessionDelegate *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[MyURLSessionDelegate alloc] init];
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
  
- (NSURLSession *)configuredSession {
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSLog(@"MyURLSessionDelegate=====>working=====>line 16 : %@", sessionConfig);

    // Load the client certificate
    NSString *pathToCertificate = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xyz" ofType:@"pem"];
    NSLog(@"pathToCertificate ====> : %@", pathToCertificate);
    NSData *certificateData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pathToCertificate];
    NSLog(@"MyURLSessionDelegate=====>working=====>line 21 : %@", certificateData);
    NSString *base64Certificate = [certificateData base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    NSLog(@"Base64 Encoded Certificate: %@", base64Certificate);
  


    if (!certificateData) {
        NSLog(@"Client certificate not found");
        return nil;
    }
    
    // Create a custom SSL configuration with the client certificate
    NSDictionary *sslSettings = @{
        (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLCertificates: @[certificateData],
        (NSString *)kCFStreamSSLValidatesCertificateChain: @NO // Disable certificate chain validation if needed
    };
    
    sessionConfig.TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol = kTLSProtocol1;
    sessionConfig.TLSMaximumSupportedProtocol = kTLSProtocol12;
    sessionConfig.TLSMinimumSupportedProtocol = kTLSProtocol12;
    sessionConfig.TLSMaximumSupportedProtocol = kTLSProtocol13;
    
    sessionConfig.connectionProxyDictionary = sslSettings;
    
    // Create and return NSURLSession with custom configuration and delegate
    return [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
}

#pragma mark - NSURLSessionDelegate Methods

// Implement NSURLSessionDelegate methods as needed

@end
```

```
**AppDelegate.mm**

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import <Firebase.h>

#import <React/RCTBundleURLProvider.h>

#import <UserNotifications/UserNotifications.h>

#import <RNCPushNotificationIOS.h>

#import <TrustKit/TrustKit.h>

#import "MyURLSessionDelegate.h"

#import "SSLPinning.h"

#import "ClientSecurity.h"



@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

{ 

  [FIRApp configure];

  self.moduleName = @"xyz_app";
  self.initialProps = @{};

  UNUserNotificationCenter *center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];

  center.delegate = self;

NSURLSession *session = [[MyURLSessionDelegate sharedInstance] configuredSession];

NSLog(@"session configuration: %@", session.configuration);


// Create the URL

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://test.example.com];



// Create the request

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";



// Set the parameters

NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"username": @“example”, @"password": @“Example@123};

NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:nil];

// Set the request body

[request setHTTPBody:postData];



// Set the content type

[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];



// Create a data task with the session

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    // Check for errors

    if (error) {

        NSLog(@"SS Error: %@", error);

        return;

    }

    // Log the raw response data

    NSLog(@"SS Raw Response Data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);


    // Parse the response data (assuming it's JSON for example)

    NSError *jsonError = nil;

    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&jsonError];

    // Check for JSON parsing errors

    if (jsonError) {

        NSLog(@"SS JSON Error: %@", jsonError);

        return;

    }

    // Now you can work with the JSON response

    NSLog(@"SS Response: %@", json);

}];



// Resume the task to start the request

[dataTask resume];    

  return [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

}

- (NSURL *)sourceURLForBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge

{

#if DEBUG

  return [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index"];

#else

  return [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];

#endif

}

// Required for the register event.

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken

{

 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:deviceToken];

}

// Required for the notification event. You must call the completion handler after handling the remote notification.

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo

fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler

{

  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveRemoteNotification:userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:completionHandler];

}

// Required for the registrationError event.

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error

{

 [RNCPushNotificationIOS didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:error];

}

// Required for localNotification event

- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center

didReceiveNotificationResponse:(UNNotificationResponse *)response

         withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(void))completionHandler
{
  [RNCPushNotificationIOS didReceiveNotificationResponse:response];
}

//Called when a notification is delivered to a foreground app.

-(void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter *)center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification *)notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
  completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionSound | UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert | UNNotificationPresentationOptionBadge);
}

@end
```

I am getting following error

`session configuration:

<NSURLSessionConfiguration: 0x15df19980>

**
My info.plist file**

```
`<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>example.com</key> <!-- Replace with your domain -->
        <dict>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSTemporaryExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSAllowsLocalNetworking</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
`
```

Let me know whats going wrong here.

I have tried above code but getting 403.

Answer (score 0):

Dear **Pranjali Wagh**

First of all I recommends you to not use `CERTIFICATE` directly instead of it use `PUBLICK KEY` which don't have expiration issue.

Now follow me step by step to integrate **SSL Pinning**

1. Use trustkit for SSL Pinning in IOS, inside podfile add:

   `pod 'TrustKit', '1.6.5'`
2. Inside `ios/AlmanaDoctorsApp/AppDelegate.m` add:

```
#import <TrustKit/TrustKit.h> // Import TrustKit
#import <TrustKit/TSKPinningValidator.h> // Import TSKPinningValidator
#import <TrustKit/TSKPinningValidatorCallback.h> // Import TSKPinningValidatorCallback

// in the end of Dynamic *t = [Dynamic new] before return

// TrustKit configuration
    void (^loggerBlock)(NSString *) = ^void(NSString *message)
    {
        NSLog(@"TrustKit log: %@", message);
    };
    [TrustKit setLoggerBlock:loggerBlock];

    NSDictionary *trustKitConfig =
    @{
      kTSKSwizzleNetworkDelegates: @YES,
      kTSKPinnedDomains: @{
              @"pa-api.almanahospital.com.sa" : @{
                      kTSKIncludeSubdomains: @YES,
                      kTSKEnforcePinning: @YES,
                      kTSKDisableDefaultReportUri: @YES,
                      kTSKPublicKeyHashes : @[
                              @"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=",
                              @"BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB="
                              ],
                      },
              },
      };
    [TrustKit initSharedInstanceWithConfiguration:trustKitConfig];
    [TrustKit sharedInstance].pinningValidatorCallback = ^(TSKPinningValidatorResult *result, NSString *notedHostname, TKSDomainPinningPolicy *policy) {
        if (result.finalTrustDecision == TSKTrustEvaluationFailedNoMatchingPin) {
            NSLog(@"TrustKit certificate matching failed");
            // Handle certificate matching failure
        }
    };
```

3. Replace `@"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="` with actual `PUBLICK KEY` of your certificate. AND `BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB=` with your backup `PUBLICK KEY`

NOTE: if you don't have BACKUP Public key, its ok just add your publick key with `@"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="` it will work fine.

4. Now install all dependencies `cd ios/` and  `pod update`

Hope it will work as you as expected.

Comment: Hi @Aqeel Ahmad thank you so much for your response. Actually we used to use PUBLIC key in past with the same TrustKIt but now our client want us to use certificate directly, fo you know the way for it. I appreciate your help.